# I want the mutation observer to listen if its target node is itself is removed in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, mutation-observers

I am using mutation observer on a target node. It fires if any of the child nodes or properties change. But I have a case where I had to handle the target node itself being removed. This is not working. Is there a way to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MutationObservers can watch for 3 things:

- An attribute change
- A text content change
- A child list change

Then optionally those change events can be bubbled up, so if you want to changes on both the target and all of the target's children, you can do that.

This means what you want cannot be done by listening to your target. You would need to attach an observer to the target's parent node, and listen for a childList change on the parent that removes the node you want to track.

e.g. instead of this fake example of what you were hoping for

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer(target, {
  // Fake non-existent option
  parent: true
});
```

you do

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
   var targetRemoved = mutations.some(function(mutation){
     return mutation.removedNodes.indexOf(target) !== -1;
   });

   if (targetRemoved) callback();
});
observer(target.parentNode, {
  childList: true
});
```

Comment: Is there any kind of hack that can help me to achieve listening to target nodes removal  ?? I have a case where i am stuck with this problem

Answer (score 0):

[can-dom-mutate](https://canjs.com/doc/can-dom-mutate.html) can do this:

```
import domMutate from "can-dom-mutate";
domMutate.onNodeRemoval(yourEleement, function(){

})
```

It does this by listening on the entire document for element removal.

Answer (score 0):

@loganfsmyth answer, but fixed missing indexOf method on NodeList by converting to array and rewritten to actual js syntax:

```js
    const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
      const targetRemoved = mutations.some((mutation) => Array.from(mutation.removedNodes).includes(target));
      if (targetRemoved) callback();
    });
    observer(target.parentNode, {
      childList: true
    });
```

thank you @loganfsmyth

Happy coding :)